# Magento user's Linux home directory (for private RSA key)

Tags: magento-enterprise

`apache` runs Magento on our Linux server, and I'm trying to find out where the home directory for this user would be. I need to place a private key for SFTP access for Magento's extension.

There is `/var/www`, so would I have a directory, `/var/www/.ssh/` here and put the private key there?

Furthermore, I'm not even sure if this will work when a Magento extension will attempt to upload a file via key-anthenticating SFTP. I do have the password-authentication SFTP already set up, and that works great. This might be a little off-topic, however.

Comment: I would try one of the Linux oriented StackExchange sites. This has not too much to do with Magento and more with server configuration

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Linux or server configuration

Comment: if your question is how php can access the user home directory $_SERVER['HOME'] may, depending on server, have this info.

Answer (score 1):

You have to run in the shell  `echo $HOME`or `cd ~/ && pwd`. It will show the home directory for current user. You will just append the path with .ssh and place your key there. 
Apache is just reading files and allowed to write in media and var.

P.S. This topic has nothing to do with Magento